# Gathering multiple multiple lists together

Tags: python, events, python-3.x

I'm creating a game, which has keyboard events, and an evented system on which functions can be registered, and are required to return two lists (of any size): a list of game-time events, and a list of real-time events (in this order).  The event-runner will then

I am in the process of refactoring the code to do this.  In the previous system, events would manually merge their events with the main game-time/real-time event queues.

I am attempting to refactor the code which triggers all events when a key is pressed/released.  The current code:

```
class KeyReleaseEventRunner
    GameEvents = []
    RealEvents = []        

    def __call__(self):
        """Run all relevant events."""

        # Run key-specific key release events
        KeyReleaseEvent[self.key]()

        # Run key-specific key toggle events
        KeyToggleEvent[self.key](False)

        # Run generic key release events
        KeyReleaseEvent(self.key)

        # Run generic key toggle events
        KeyToggleEvent(self.key, False)
```

My question is how to merge all of the events from each of these functions.

**Is there an easier, readable way to do this?:**

```
    def __call__(self):
        """Run all relevant events."""

        # Run key-specific key release events
        g_events, r_events = KeyReleaseEvent[self.key]()
        self.GameEvents.extend(g_events)
        self.RealEvents.extend(r_events)

        # Run key-specific key toggle events
        g_events, r_events = KeyToggleEvent[self.key](False)
        self.GameEvents.extend(g_events)
        self.RealEvents.extend(r_events)

        # Run generic key release events
        g_events, r_events = KeyReleaseEvent(self.key)
        self.GameEvents.extend(g_events)
        self.RealEvents.extend(r_events)

        # Run generic key toggle events
        g_events, r_events = KeyToggleEvent(self.key, False)
        self.GameEvents.extend(g_events)
        self.RealEvents.extend(r_events)

        # Events must maintain sorted-ness
        self.GameEvents.sort()
        self.RealEvents.sort()
```

I don't want to create a method on KeyReleaseEventRunner (this situation is in several other places, and often uses local variables instead of GameEvents/RealEvents).

**More generally, is there a better solution to having these functions return two lists?**

It's possible to differentiate between events in g_events and r_events.

**Edit:**

To clear up any confusion about the objects being both callable and indexable:

It may be worth noting that instances of `Event` are interfaces by which functions are registered, and when called, call all registered objects.  `KeyToggleEvent` and `KeyReleaseEvent`(and also `KeyPressEvent`) are instances of a subclass of `Event`, by which other modules can register key-specific events (by registering to `KeyReleaseEvent[key]`), and non-key specific events (by registering to `KeyReleaseEvent`).

Comment: Why are `KeyReleaseEvent` and `KeyToggleEvent` both callable and indexable? What does indexing mean in this context?

Comment: @senderle Shouldn't matter for the question, but it's a complex interface.  Indexing with a key returns an `Event` for that specific key.  Both `KeyToggleEvent` and `KeyReleaseEvent` are instances of a `KeyEvent` class which subclasses `Event` to allow `__getitem__` to return an Event specific to a key.

Comment: @senderle I have updated my question to give a better explanation of how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I wondered about the combination of indexing and calling is that it seems to overcomplicate your interface. This might not be what you wanted to hear, but I can't help but feel that you'd be better off using keyword arguments rather than indexing to specify event subsets. Then you could create a list of arguments and a list of objects, and iterate over them. Something like this:

```
arg_list = [{'key':self.key, 'foo':False}, {'key':self.key}, ... ]
handlers = [KeyReleaseEvent, KeyToggleEvent, ...]
for handler, args in zip(arg_list, handlers):
    g_events, r_events = handler(*args)
    self.GameEvents.extend(g_events)
    self.RealEvents.extend(r_events)
self.GameEvents.sort()
self.RealEvents.sort()
```

Or even more concisely:

```
gevents_revents = [handler(*args) for handler, args in zip(arg_list, handlers)]
all_gevents, all_revents = zip(*gevents_revents)
self.GameEvents.extend(e for sublist in all_gevents for e in sublist)
self.RealEvents.extend(e for sublist in all_revents for e in sublist)
```

You could, of course, still do something like this with your current setup. But it would be a bit less elegant, I fear.

I also think you should consider using a different data structure for your event queues. Instead of a simple list, have you considered using a priority queue, such as the one provided by [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html)? This would allow you to avoid repeated (O(n log n)) sorts. Individual insertions and removals would be O(log n), which is better than the naive approach using lists (O(n)) but worse than a more careful approach (O(1)). In effect, you'd be spreading the work out over time, as individual items are removed from the queue, instead of doing it all at once, in a single sort. But you would still get O(n) merges!

Whether that's the right approach depends on your own case. (For example, if you need to see the order of events in the future, this isn't the best approach.) I can write more about this if you're interested, but the basic idea is that you can use `heapq.heapify` (O(n)) instead of `sort` (O(n log n)).

```
arg_list = [{'key':self.key, 'foo':False}, {'key':self.key}, ... ]
handlers = [KeyReleaseEvent, KeyToggleEvent, ...]
for handler, args in zip(arg_list, handlers):
    g_events, r_events = handler(*args)
    self.GameEvents.extend(g_events)
    self.RealEvents.extend(r_events)
heapq.heapify(self.GameEvents)
heapq.heapify(self.RealEvents)
```

And then to get the highest-priority item off the queue:

```
next_game_event = heapq.heappop(self.GameEvents)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I'm pretty sure the interface is simpler than it sounds initially (it provides a very convenient interface for registering keyboard events, that I can't elaborate on in a comment).  I can quite easily sort the events coming from all of the handlers and merge them in if I want to avoid sorting the main arrays.  However, given timsort's excellent performance on partially sorted arrays, I wasn't too worried about re-sorting (these events are also already spread out over time).  I will need to take a closer look at the code you've posted before I say more.

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding the data structure!  You're right that a heap/priority queue would be much better for insertions/removals, thanks for bringing to light the advantages.  I wish I could give another +1 :)